# Will changing amplitude change the frequency?

Tags: waves, frequency

Will changing the amplitude change the frequency of a wave, or is it possible for a specific frequency (50 Hz. for example) to generate from shifting amplitude patterns?

Comment: It may change the wavelength though . Consider transmission of a wave on a lighter string to a heavier and more stiff one .

Comment: If the amount of power driving the wave is fixed, then yes, increasing the amplitude would certainly lower the frequency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's completely possible to change the amplitude (the difference between the maximum value of the wave and the minimum) without changing the frequency.

Think this in AC, where you can have signals with different voltage but the same frequency.

To illustrate it I'll show you this for a harmonic wave:
$$x(t)=Acos(\omega t+\phi)$$
You can vary the amplitude (for example, adding another wave of the same frequency and phase) and the resulting wave will be just:
$$x'(t)=A'cos(\omega t+\phi)$$

Note that if we add two waves, in general, the new frequency does not need to be the same.

Comment: Do not forget the this applies for waves generally. But electromagnetic waves, for example, are special case where amplitude and frequency are bound together.

Comment: @TomášZato How are amplitude, i.e. intensity, and frequency tied together in EM waves? Wavelength and frequency are correlated through the speed of light, but the amplitude has nothing to do with this.